# Having issues with command line and Postgres 12 psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am a complete novice. I am following the freecodeacademy tutorial on Postgres and set up the environment fine with the bin and lib.

My issue comes with his next instructions which insinuate I can just put 'psql' and then it will open my environment to postgres. This is not the case for me. It actually prompts me to enter my password for my User profile as in my laptop userprofile and when I do, the password is marked as incorrect. for example, it's not showing C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin> like I pathed it in the environment settings. Just my regular user profile.

The only way I have been able to enter the environment is using 'psql -U postgres' and then entering the password I set for it.

psql --help also doesn't work.

I was hoping anyone had any advice for me as a newbie (alternative resource/solution-wise)? I don't have cmd line or any coding experience so my troubleshooting with this is not good because it's very foreign to me.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's the error saying?

Comment: Hi Dennis, it is simply a password failure message it says:
psql: Error could not connect to server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Lebene"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to connect to the `postgres` database as user `postgres`:

```sh
psql -U postgres -d postgres
```

You can set the environment variables `PGUSER` and `PGDATABASE` to the user and database you want by default.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I am doing this but in the course it seems that the instructor doesn't have to do that? 

So will I need to use 'psql -U postgres -d postgres' or 'psql -U postgres postgres' with the password every time? That's my situation now. If that's the case, that is fine, I will just copy/paste it on a sticky note or get used to typing it quickly. I just want to make sure there isn't a problem on my side that's disallowing me to do the same. This is the tutorial for reference at a timestamp that demonstrates. https://youtu.be/qw--VYLpxG4?t=2032

Comment: In the end I moved from regular windows cmd prompt to using GitBash and haven't had over arching issues since. I just need to understand/study how to set my permissions and defaults so that I don't run into permission denied issues etc.